# Splitting element in an array such that the new array has 2 subset solution to the subset sum to zero problem

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I have a problem that is not quite the same as a subset sum problem and is best shown with an example.

Given the N item array of real numbers which is guaranteed to sum up to zero,

```
Example: [13.6, 21, 49, -40.8, -22.4, -20.4]
```

Find a way to split the last item in the array, -20.4 in this case, into two numbers which sum to the original last item, where when solving for the subset sum problem, there is two or more subset that sum up to exactly zero. For this example, the solution is as such:

```
[13.6, 21, 49, -40.8, -22.4, -(20.4-x), -x]
```

Let x be 8.2

```
[13.6, 21, 49, -40.8, -22.4, -12.2, -8.2]
```

Then the two subsets that sum to zero is

```
[13.6, 21, -22.4, -12.2] and [49, -40.8, -8.2]
```

The problem is what is an efficient way to find all the possible x that will enable a valid subset splitting afterward. A more general problem is to find all the possible ways to split the last entry into m different entries such that there are m valid subsets that sum up to zero.

I am quite stuck and unsure how to do proceed. Thank you for any help or advice given! Also, if possible, any solution or hints for implementation in Python would be most appreciated!